# Doesn't display the whole window in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, graphics-card, display, dell-inspiron, netbook

My Dell Inspiron Mini 10 Netbook doesn't display the whole window in Windows XP. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Any helpful answers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Post a screenshot please so we can help

Answer (score 0):

Increase the resolution of your screen.

Right click on any portion of your desktop without an icon on it,

go to properties

go to settings tab

Increase your resolution to a higher or highest setting.

If the does not work, update your video driver, and try the prior steps again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it says my netbook does not meet the minimum requirement for installing the software when I tried to install the video driver downloaded from http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/DriverDetails/Product/inspiron-mini10?driverId=16H70&osCode=WW1&fileId=2731109303&languageCode=EN&categoryId=VI and ftp://ftp.dell.com/Pages/Drivers/inspiron-mini1012.html. By the way, the netbook had no problem before and I have never changed any hardware of the netbook.

Comment: The first driver you linked to is for an Intel Graphics_Media 945GSE/GM965 driver, and the second link is for a number of different drivers, one of which is the same as the first link, although it goes by a different name, but has the version number. Is this the driver you need based on the service tag for your laptop? I don't mean this to sound like a rhetorical question, it's important that all details are checked before going onto the next step. The reason why I bring it up is the prompt you got about meeting minimum requirements, that happens when its the wrong one sometimes.

Comment: Another thing when checking for drivers using the service tag, it will give you  only the  drivers that are needed for the laptop, not a list of video drivers to choose from as the one from the ftp site gave. if you search just the model number, it will give a list to choose from.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I installed the right one, but still the netbook doesn't display the whole window in Windows XP. Any other ideas or suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Nope, sorry, in all my years of playing with computers, it always was a resolution issue or a driver that would not allow the computer give the proper resolution. As suggested earlier, put up a picture of the problem, a screenshot if it can be done.